# Stored procedure causing error

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, paging

I declared 2 parameters for my stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[paging_select]
    @startrowindex int,
    @maximumrows int
as
begin
    select username,firstname,lastname from crudtable ;
end
```

Simply passing the value as following but when executing it, it is causing an error:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(getconnectionstring());
con.Open();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("paging_select", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startrowindex", 1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@maximumrows", 3);
//  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalrows", 1);

cmd.Connection = con;
sda.Fill(dt);  
sda.Dispose();
gridview.DataSource = dt;
gridview.DataBind();
con.Close();
```

Error was:

> Procedure or function 'paging_select' expects parameter
>   '@startrowindex', which was not supplied.

Help Please.

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass command object to the `SqlDatAdapter`.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText="paging_select";
cmd.Connection=con;
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```

PS: Always use [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) block to dispose objects automatically (*IDisposable*).

```
using(SqlConnection cn=new SqlConnection())
{
  //
}
```

Comment: Thanks.its working now.
Can you explain why it wasn't working before ?

Comment: @user1544975: you had a `SqlDataAdapter` but **no SELECT command** assigned to that adapter to actually fetch data on the call to `.Fill()` ....